# The order of a conjugacy class is bounded by the index of the center

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-actions

If the center of a group $G$ is of index $n$, prove that every conjugacy class has at most $n$ elements. (This question is from Dummit and Foote, page 130, 3rd edition.)

Here is my attempt: we have
$$
  |G| = |C_G (g_i)| |G : C_G (g_i)| \,,
  \quad
  |C_G (g_i)| = |Z(G)| \cdot  |C_G (g_i):Z(G)| \,.
$$
Then
$$
  |G| = |Z(G)| \cdot |C_G (g_i):Z(G)| \cdot |G : C_G (g_i)| \,.
$$
Then
$$
  n = |C_G (g_i):Z(G)| \cdot |G : C_G (g_i)| \,.
$$

But $|C_G (g_i):Z(G)|$ is a positive integer as $Z(G)$ is subgroup of  $C_G (g_i)$.

If $|G : C_G (g_i)|$ bigger than $n$, then $|C_G (g_i):Z(G)| \cdot |G : C_G (g_i)|$ is bigger than $n$.

But $|C_G (g_i):Z(G)| \cdot |G : C_G (g_i)| = n$, contradiction.

Then $|G : C_G (g_i)| \leq n$ and this completes the proof.

Is this proof right or not?

Comment: What if $G$ is infinite?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your proof is correct, but you can simplify the end by saying that $$[G:C_G(g_i)] \leq [C_G(g_i):Z(G)]\cdot[G:C_G(g_i)] =n$$ Actually a contradiction is not needed.

Comment: thanx :) you are right :)

Answer (score 0):

From the work you did you can also prove the slightly stonger fact, that:
$$
|x^G|\Big|[G:Z(G)]
$$
We know that $Z(G)\leq C_G(x)\leq G$ and $|x^G|=[G:C_G(x)]$ so since the index is multplicative (if $H\leq K\leq G$ then $[G:H]=[K:H][G:K]$) we get that
$$[G:Z(G)]=[C_G(x):Z(G)][G:C_G(x)]$$
And we get the result